# Transit visa at sweden for syrian

Tags: usa, transit, sweden, syrian-citizens

I am a Syrian citizen and I have a tourist visa to USA. I want to travel from Russia to USA and transit through Sweden, then ask for asylum at the transit area.

1. Do I need a transit visa at Stockholm airport (knowing that I will ask for asylum at transit visa in the international area after missing my plane intentionally)?
2. Are the Swedish authorities going to force me to go back to Russia, or on to the USA knowing that I just have a tourist visa for those mentioned countries, or will they give me asylum?

Comment: I feel for your situation, but this question is off topic on the site. I think whether or not you can get a transit visa is the least of your troubles. Talk to the first Swedish official you meet and ask for help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asylum.

Comment: I disagree there are a multitude of reasons why people travel.  Seeking asylum, working, traveling or just simply walking on the wrong side of the street, it doesn't matter as long as the question is about the actual traveling

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking reasons to disobey the law


Comment: @Frietjeoorlog Why is this against the law.

Comment: I'm far from an expert in asylum, but you seem to be making this more complicated. As Kate Gregory says, there is no point in 'missing your flight'. As soon as you get to Sweden, ask for asylum. Delay will make matters worse. As to whether the Swedish authorities will grant you asylum, that is entirely up to them and dependant on your circumstances. Make sure you read up on what Sweden considers grounds for granting asylum.

Comment: If the Swedes decide to deport you it will probably be to a country where you have right of residence. That's most likely to be Syria.

Comment: @Dirty-flow At least the part about the transit visa is uncontroversially on-topic. A transit visa is squarely travel even in the most narrow interpretation of the term.